# cannot update pull request file in a branch by use push {remote} {src branch}:{dst branch}

Tags: git, github

After pull request file was resolved in online git editor, it yielded a new branch called PRmerge, and the file copied to local,
but then why did it fail update the file back in this branch of pull request by using push (after all prerequirement git fetch upstream .., editing, git add ..., git commit -am "..", etc correctly fulfilled; let upstream is the source of fork):

```
git push origin master:origin/PRmerge
```

or with `-f`
If it's checked on github, it's simply not affected whatsoever.
What is the fault and How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is trying to push to the branch `origin/origin/PRmerge`

Try `git push origin master:PRmerge`